# Filling Tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, grid-layout

I'm having some trouble get my frames and widgets to fill out the tkinter window. I don't know what I have wrong here. I have been trying to mess around with *columnspan* *sticky* and *width/height*. I am fairly new to using Tkinter and still trying to figure out the basics of widgets and geometry management.

```
def comments():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Comments")
    root.geometry("300x200+300+300")

    var = tk.IntVar()

    top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="red", width=350, height=50)
    name_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Username", bg='red', fg="yellow", font=("arial, 17"))
    name_entry = tk.Entry(top_frame)

    comment_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="yellow", width=40, height=70, bd="3px", relief=GROOVE)
    comment_entry = tk.Text(comment_frame, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN, width=40, height=5)
    comment = comment_entry.get('1.0', 'end-1c')

    like_dislike_frame = tk.Frame(root, relief=GROOVE, bg='green', width=300, height=50)
    #like_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Like").grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx="6px")
    #dislike_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Dislike").grid(row=2)
    like_button = tk.Checkbutton(like_dislike_frame, text="Like", font=("arial, 12"), onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable=var, bg='green', fg='yellow')
    dislike_button = tk.Checkbutton(like_dislike_frame, text="Dislike", font=("arial, 12"), onvalue=1,offvalue=0, variable=var, bg='green', fg='yellow')


def save_comment():

    #if like_dislike == 0:
        #dislikes =+ 1
        #opinion = dislike
    #elif like_dislike == 1:
        #likes =+ 1
        #opinion = like
    
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour > 12:
        hour = now.hour-12
        meridiem = 'pm'
    else:
        hour = now.hour
        meridiem = 'am'
        
    timestamp = str(now.month)+'/'+str(now.day)+'/'+str(now.year)+'\t'+str(hour)+':'+str(now.minute)+':'+str(now.second)

    with open(comments_file, 'a') as file:
        file.write(comment + timestamp + meridiem + '\r\n\n')

    exit_comments = tk.messagebox.askyesno('Exit', 'Return to About Page?')
    if exit_comments == True:
        root.destroy()


submit_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Submit", command=save_comment)

top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=EW)
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx="5px")
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, padx="5px")
comment_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
comment_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=EW)

like_dislike_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
like_button.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, padx="6px")
dislike_button.grid(row=2, column=1, padx="6px")
submit_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I am also having trouble getting the checkbutton to work. I want the user to be able to select "Like" or "Dislike" and have their selection stay checked until they submit their comment. Also with the save_comment function, it is NOT getting the text from the Text widget and writing it to the file along with the date and time

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: it seems for me that your frame are larger than the window. What is that you want to change? Please be very specific.

Comment: I edited my code so the indentation is fixed. My intentions are to have all frames fit inside the window while also stretching to fit if they are too small. I also want to center the like, dislike and submit widgets in the center of each of their respective columns and rows. I want the "Username" Label to be halfway across with the Entry widget fit to the other half while only going to the third column

Comment: Your updated code will raise `NameError: name 'like_dislike_frame' is not defined` at the line `submit_button = tk.Button(like_dislike_frame, text="Submit", command=save_comment)`.

Comment: acw1668:  I don't see how it would raise the error. I set the variable like_dislike_frame before the submit_button

Comment: `like_dislike_frame` is created inside `comment()` function and it is a local variable.